# How to get milliseconds in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column with `DATETIME` type. It seems to be storing data in date and time but not in milliseconds.

What can I do to ensure milliseconds are captured in addition?

Example:

```
insert into mytable (datecreated) values (now());

select * from mutable; -- fetches 2014-10-06 17:44:19 date followed by hr:min:sec but not millisecond
```

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73

Comment: quick google search suggests only 5.6 supports storing microseconds. Guess thats it...

Comment: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73 is the client version, not the server version. `SELECT @@VERSION;` for the server version... needs 5.6+ for native milli- or microsecond datetime and timestamp handling.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html
However, microseconds cannot be stored into a column of any temporal data type. Any microseconds part is discarded.

You can store your date as string.

Comment: Could of course be stored as DECIMAL(13,3) - not sure what happens on January 19th 2038 though :-$